# How do I get only the parent/child grouped products in a custom Woocommerce loop?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a Bootstrap Accordion in a custom page template, where the Panel headings will contain the parent Grouped Products and inside each of these panel's body, will be the child products of that grouped product.

Suppose, I have Parent product 1 (Which has child product 1 and child product 2) and parent product 2 (Which has child product 3 and child product 4)(These are grouped products). These products are in a Product category "Coaching Sessions".

I have created a custom loop but it's not working. It's displaying every product in that category. The code -

```
    <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'product_cat' => 'coaching-sessions',
                'terms' => 'grouped',
                'order'     => 'ASC',
                'parent' => 0
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
```

how do i fetch only the parent or only the child grouped products using this query?

Sorry if the terms I described appear a bit naive, I am not an expert by any means. Thanks you for your kind reply. Any help will be appreciated.